# Eclipse is hiding a package from me, why is that?

Tags: java, eclipse, package

My problem is that, i have package that disappeared!

I have a list of packages, once i create package name model, and it hided this package from me, i mean i cant see it in project explorer.

Why it can happened?

Here's [a link](http://postimg.org/image/szu4pacnt/)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclispe hide it if there aren't file in it, put a file in the package and you should see it

Comment: how can i put file in it if i cant see it? :)

Comment: When You create javascript file You Can specificate The package White you create It